# Sequence with largest size of subsequence having each element as same

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, sequence

I want to find out the largest continuous subsequence having every element equal to 5 .

I tried writing a code for this but couldn't figure out the right method

example ->  if sequence is like 5 5 1 0 93 43 5 5 5 5 21 
            answer will be 4 since  4 continuous 5's are present in the array .
P.S. - I'm a newbie stuck on it .

```
int large(int a[],int n)
{
    int i=0,j=0,sublen=0;
    while(i<n)
    {
        if(a[i]==1)
        {
            sublen++;
            for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
            {
                if(a[j]==1)
                {
                    sublen++;
                }
                else
                {
                    i=j+1;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }   
        else
        {
            i++;
        }
   }
   return sublen;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply iterate through the sequence, when you see a 5 then increment a counter otherwise reset the counter to 0. When you increment the counter test to see if it's the largest value it's held so far. At the end return the largest value.

Something like:

```
int large(const int *a, int n)
{
    int sublen = 0, counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (a[i] == 5) { // found a 5
            ++counter;
            if (sublen < counter) { // test for largest value so far
                sublen = counter;
            }
        } else { // not a 5
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
    return sublen;
}
```

Comment: is their any other optimal way of doing it , coz it's not good for operating on large arrays @Blastfurnace

Comment: @Muskan You could exit early if the largest sequence found so far is greater than the number of elements remaining to test but the algorithm is still O(n).